# Reactjs api data from unsplash is not being stored in this.state.photos but is being logged out on the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native, asynchronous

when I make a call to the unsplash api in the componentDidMount, the this.state.photos data is still undefined after the api call, but when I console.log out the response to the console, the data is showing. You can see thay I have console.log the informations. (response.data and this.state.photos). The this.state.photos is the one being undefined and not showing  the data. I am using ReactJS. Anyone know why? Please see code below. Thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Footer from "../components/Footer";
import axios from "axios";
import NavBar from "../components/NavBar";
import AOS from 'aos';


class CountryPage extends React.Component{



    state = {
        country: null,
        photos: []
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get(`https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/${this.props.match.params.name}`)
            .then(response=> {
                this.setState({
                    country: response.data[0]
                })
                console.log(this.state.country)
            })
            axios.get(`https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=${Access_Key}&query=bike`)
            .then(response=> {
                this.setState({
                    photos: response.data[0]
                })
                console.log(response.data)
                console.log(this.state.photos)
            })
            AOS.init({
                duration: 1000
            });
    }




    render() {

        if(!this.state.country){
            return <p>Loading</p>
         }


        return(
            <div className="countryPageBack">
                <NavBar/>
                 <div className="container">
                     <div className="countryAndFlag animate__bounceIn">
                        <h1 className="countryPageTitle">{`${this.props.match.params.name} - (${this.state.country.nativeName})`}</h1>
                        <img className="countryPageFlag" src={this.state.country.flag}/>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-left" className="countryBasics">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Basic Info</h3>
                        <div className="basicDesc">{`Located in ${this.state.country.region}, ${this.state.country.name} has a population of ${this.state.country.population} people`}</div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Currency: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.currencies[0].name} - {`${this.state.country.currencies[0].symbol}`}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Langauges Spoken: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.languages[0].name}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Capitols: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.capital}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-right" className="countryRegion">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Regional Info</h3>
                        <div className="propertyName">Region: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.region}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Subregion: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.subregion}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Timezones: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.timezones}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Area: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.area}</span></div>
                    </div>
                    <div data-aos="fade-left" className="countryOthers">
                        <h3 className="sectionTitle">Other Info</h3>
                        <div className="propertyName">Calling Code: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.callingCodes}</span></div> 
                        <div className="propertyName">Country Code: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.alpha3Code}</span></div>
                        <div className="propertyName">Main Domain: <span className="propertyValue">{this.state.country.topLevelDomain}</span></div>
                    </div>                           
            </div>
            <Footer/>
            </div>

        )
    }
}

export default CountryPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are setting the wrong key to the state.

I tried a similar call to Unsplash API ([ref](https://unsplash.com/documentation#response-16)) for fetching photos. I believe you should change your set code to

```
this.setState({
    photos: response.data.results[0]
})
```

in case you want the first photo to be added to photos or `response.data.results` if you want the entire list.